# How to extract common words of a bunch of strings

Tags: string, algorithm

Let's say we have strings like this:

```
Tommy is a very good child
Tommy has a very wonderful child
Tommy loves his very child
```

I want to extract the common words of above 3 strings as:

```
Tommy*very*child
```

How am I supposed to do that? Thanks.

Comment: By "part" do you mean, "whole word"? Or can it be a single character or group of characters? **EDIT** Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @JonathanLam, I mean in word units. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the data structure called `inverted index`

First you assign an unique integer to each of your input strings. Then, the idea is that for each word in the input strings, you want to compute a list of integers denoting the strings in which the word occurs. Notice that you can easily do that just processing all the input strings. In your case, in order to get words occurring in all strings, you can output words which list of occurrences has the same number of entries as the number of strings in the input.

For more details, please refer here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** I just realized @Joce's comment, and I put my answer in JavaScript. But it can easily be adapted to other languages. If it's not JavaScript, treat this as pseudocode.

**EDIT 2** Whoa! It worked beautifully on my first try! See working example at [JSFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/7xmazb1b/).

This might be a very bulky scripting answer, but here goes:

Given the original sentences as string arrays:

```
var sentences = [
    "Tommy is a very good child",
    "Tommy has a very wonderful child",
    "Tommy loves his very child"
];
```

You can try to create an array of words from each array, storing it in a multidimensional array.

```
var split = [];
for(var i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
    split[i] = sentences[i].split(" ");
}
```

You could also remove word duplicates here, but I don't know how to on the spot, but you could probably get some simple algorithm to do it. Unless you'll allow duplicate word phrases, of course.

Then, you could create another array with words that are the same, and fill it like so:

```
var same = [];
for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {             // loop through sentences
    for(var j = 0; j < split[i].length; j++) {      // go through each sentence for new words
        if(same.indexOf(split[i][j]) <= -1) {       // if not already found
            var inAll = true;
            for(var k = 0; k < split.length; k++) { // check if in every sentence
                if(k == i) continue;
                if(split[k].indexOf(split[i][j]) <= -1) inAll = false; // if not found, make `inAll` false
            }
            if(inAll) same.push(split[i][j]);       // if found in all other sentences, add to array `same`
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry this is such a convoluted answer, but it should show the logic behind the algorithm. If you want to, try changing around the strings on JSFiddle.

Comment: I know it's pretty old but I came across to your answer because I needed it in JS. It worked beautifully indeed! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To keep it simple, I'll use [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs#union) here:

```
var a = 'Hello world'.split(' ');
var b = 'Hello again world!'.split(' ');
var c = 'Hello tomorrow'.split(' ');

var commonWords = _.union(a, b, c);
// => ['Hello']
```

I used `lodash` simply because it provides a succint method for what, in reality, you're trying to do, which is a **union**, based on (for example) delimiters and transforms.

A **union** is language-independent: the algorithm you use to implement the union will differ somewhat based on the language you choose.

You can use that within a function, where you define delimiters (for example, do I separate at a space?) and transforms (for example, do the words have to be uppercase to match?)

Comment: [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) is "A JavaScript utility library delivering consistency, modularity, performance, & extras." I wasn't sure what it was, so I'm hoping this will clarify for anyone else.